# is there a workaround for allowing facebook authentication for files in file://android_assets/www?

Tags: android, facebook

I understand that only http can be added to siteUrl in facebook

When the apk is installed in the mobile, the html files will be in the path ***file:///android_assets/www/***

This will not be accepted as siteUrl in facebook

Also this is not a valid oAuth redirect URI

So the authentication will work perfectly when its hosted in localhost or a website (ie any http), but the same html/js wont work in android app as the files will be in ***file:///android_assets path***

Is there a workaround for this? 
Currently in the index.html, I am just redirecting it to `http://www.someurl.com/index.html` so that facebook authentication will work

Comment: No, this won't work.

Comment: ya it didnt
is there a workaround ?